# How to add variable by variable value type?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with varibale *job* with levels - Manager, Supervisor, SelfEmployed, Official, Highly professional employee, Low skilled worker, Unskilled worker. I want to add new column with variable class where will be value 1 for high *class* workers and 2 for low class workers.

Data.frame will be like:

```
head(df)
# Job                  Class
# Manager               1
# Supervisor            1
# Low skilled worker    2
# Low skilled worker    2 
# Unskilled worker      2
# Manager               1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R` you can use:

```
df$Class <- ifelse(df$Job %in% c("Manager", "Supervisor"), 1, 2)
```

`dplyr` solution:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Class = ifelse(Job %in% c("Manager", "Supervisor"), 1, 2))
```

`data.table` solution:

```
setDT(df)
df[, Class := fifelse(Job %in% c("Manager", "Supervisor"), 1, 2)]
```

Data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Job, ~Class,
  "Manager", 1,
  "Supervisor", 1,
  "Low skilled worker", 2, 
  "Low Skilled worker", 2,
  "Unskilled worker", 2, 
  "Manager", 1
)
```

Comment: More concisely: `ifelse(df$Job %in% c("Manager", "Supervisor"), 1, 2)`

Comment: for `data.table` you can also use the stricter and faster alternative `fifelse()

Comment: What about if I would like to add 3th value for middle class worker?